# Image uploading on window server through php error

Tags: php, file-upload

i got a error in image uploading on window based server where it works well on localhost as well as in linux server.Firstly i manually create a folder named as **photos** in root directory & **two files** named as  **imageupload.php** & **index.php**

```
where code is
```

**index.php**

```
     <html>        
      <body>
      <form enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="imageupload.php" method="post"> 
Choose Picture:<input type="file" name="photo"/>
       <input name="submit" type="submit" value="save"/>
        </form>
        </body>
      </html>
```

**imageupload.php**

```
 <?php
  if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
      $target = "photos/"; 
  $finallink = $target.basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);

     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $finallink)) 
   { 
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
        } 
      else { 

 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
         } 
     }
    ?>
```

this code works well on localhost & as well as on linux server but i purchased a window based hosting & where as I'm **getting error on running this code on window based web server** is .

> Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.

How to fix it ? Is this issue of php code running on window based server or anything else? **Thanks for your help in advance.**

Comment: check file permission on server for storing file.

Comment: print_r($_POST);print_r($_FILES);exit;

Comment: problem solved  it's the  permission issue..thanku so much **Yogesh Suthar** for your advice & help:)

Comment: thanku **Bhavin Rana** to you.. for your advice & concerned..:)

Comment: @Hdhams , please tell us how did u change the permission in windows server?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code hope it will hlp you

```
     if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){ move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["photo"]["name"]; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["companylogo"]["tmp_name"],"companylogo/" . $_FILES["companylogo"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "companylogo/".$_FILES["companylogo"]["name"];
```